# Queries getting slow after using secondaryprefered in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, performance

We have a mongoDB replica set(1 primary + 2Secondary + 1 arbitor). Earlier we were using primarypreferred configuration in spring to connect with mongo(because of the application use case). Now we have decided to move on secondary(by using secondarypreffered). Issue is after moving to secondary query execution time increased drastically. Initially we thought this behavior is due to data and indexes are not in the RAM. So we tried to warm up hitting around thousands of queries using jmeter. On jmeter we get some performance improvement but i thinks thats because of query caching.
I used explain()on both primary and secondary for the same query and got the same winning plan. also the execution time for the query are almost same. Problem arises we increases the load on secondary. 
Examole of such query

```
2016-09-26T11:28:22.826+0530 I COMMAND  [conn4206507] command response.$cmd command: aggregate { aggregate: "buyerResponse", pipeline: [ { $match: { superProfileId: 15205907, productType: { $in: [ "CP" ] }, responseDate: { $gte: new Date(1472277502000), $lt: new Date(1474869502000) }, status: { $in: [ "Y", "K" ] } } }, { $project: { month: { $month: [ "$responseDate" ] }, superProfileId: 1, subProfileId: 1, productType: 1, productId: 1, responseType: 1, siteVisit: 1, preference: 1, callStatus: 1, isNew: 1, propertySnapshot: 1 } }, { $group: { _id: "$callStatus", superProfileId: { $first: "$superProfileId" }, subProfileId: { $first: "$subProfileId" }, productType: { $first: "$productType" }, productId: { $first: "$productId" }, responseType: { $first: "$responseType" }, month: { $first: "$month" }, siteVisit: { $first: "$siteVisit" }, preference: { $first: "$preference" }, callStatus: { $first: "$callStatus" }, isNew: { $first: "$isNew" }, projectId: { $first: "$propertySnapshot.projectId" }, count: { $sum: 1 } } } ] } keyUpdates:0 writeConflicts:0 numYields:101 reslen:50 locks:{ Global: { acquireCount: { r: 208 } }, MMAPV1Journal: { acquireCount: { r: 104 } }, Database: { acquireCount: { r: 104 } }, Collection: { acquireCount: { R: 104 } } } 513ms
```

both the query ran on almost same time and with same parameter and same data size.

```
2016-09-26T11:28:01.216+0530 I COMMAND  [conn4206507] command response.$cmd command: aggregate { aggregate: "buyerResponse", pipeline: [ { $match: { superProfileId: 18154267, productType: { $in: [ "CP" ] }, responseDate: { $gte: new Date(1472277478000), $lt: new Date(1474869478000) }, status: { $in: [ "Y", "K" ] } } }, { $project: { month: { $month: [ "$responseDate" ] }, superProfileId: 1, subProfileId: 1, productType: 1, productId: 1, responseType: 1, siteVisit: 1, preference: 1, callStatus: 1, isNew: 1, propertySnapshot: 1 } }, { $group: { _id: "$callStatus", superProfileId: { $first: "$superProfileId" }, subProfileId: { $first: "$subProfileId" }, productType: { $first: "$productType" }, productId: { $first: "$productId" }, responseType: { $first: "$responseType" }, month: { $first: "$month" }, siteVisit: { $first: "$siteVisit" }, preference: { $first: "$preference" }, callStatus: { $first: "$callStatus" }, isNew: { $first: "$isNew" }, projectId: { $first: "$propertySnapshot.projectId" }, count: { $sum: 1 } } } ] } keyUpdates:0 writeConflicts:0 numYields:669 reslen:50 locks:{ Global: { acquireCount: { r: 1344 }, acquireWaitCount: { r: 2 }, timeAcquiringMicros: { r: 417 } }, MMAPV1Journal: { acquireCount: { r: 672 }, acquireWaitCount: { r: 1 }, timeAcquiringMicros: { r: 48952 } }, Database: { acquireCount: { r: 672 } }, Collection: { acquireCount: { R: 672 } } } 2948ms
```

Comment: What's physical location of the secondary? How hardware of the secondary is compared to the primary?

Comment: All the machines have same configuration(64 GB RAM). Network latency is not the issue. You can assume all are equidistance

Comment: What's version of MongoDB? What's OS?

Comment: On the secondary the query yields 669 times vs. 101 in the primary, probably paging occurs much more on the secondary. Check that you have enough RAM for Mongo's dataset (that secondary does not run some RAM consuming app that does not leave room for mongo).

Comment: MongoDB 3.0.6. CentOS

Comment: Yes i have seen the seen the same thing but that machine is solely for mongo. No other application or something running on that box.

Comment: I have given statistics for both the query from the same secondary machine. 101 yield is not from primary its also from secondary

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/124181/discussion-between-amar-and-rlib).